# Symlink to part of the file?

Tags: filesystems, symlink

Is there possible to create file that is just a sub-sequence of bytes from another file, like a symlink, but referencing only part of the file?

Comment: Perhaps if you explain the purpose of what you are trying to do, we could suggest a solution.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, it is (somewhat) possible at least on Linux with some limitations.

The method is to create a read-write loop device that maps to a subset of the file.

eg:

```bash
# Write some data to a single file
for ((i=0;i<10000;i++)); do
    printf "%7d\n" $i
done >/var/tmp/file

# Use losetup to manage a new loopback device
# The --find option without any arguments to find an available loop device
# The --show will echo what that found device is to stdout
# We capture this to ensure the rest of the script refers to the correct device
NEW_DEV_LOOP=$(sudo losetup --show --verbose --find --show --offset 512 --sizelimit 512 /var/tmp/file)

# This will be something like /dev/loop3 depending on what devices are available
echo "NEW_DEV_LOOP = $NEW_DEV_LOOP"

# Print status
losetup -a

# Show the contents of the file and loop device
head -2 /var/tmp/file
echo ...
tail -2 /var/tmp/file
echo "==="
sudo head -2 "$NEW_DEV_LOOP"
echo ...
sudo tail -2 "$NEW_DEV_LOOP"

# Write to the loop device and show impact on the file
sudo sh -c "printf 'I was here' > '$NEW_DEV_LOOP'"
grep here /var/tmp/file

# Detatch the example loop device
sudo losetup -d "$NEW_DEV_LOOP"
```

output:

```
NEW_DEV_LOOP=/dev/loop0
loop device: /dev/loop0
/dev/loop0: [0808]:136392 (/var/tmp/file), offset 512, size 512
      0
      1
...
   9998
   9999
===
     64
     65
...
    126
    127
I was here   65
```

I believe both the offset and the size must be multiple of a block size (512 bytes).

You probably need to be root to create and access the loop device.

If you need a symlink, you can create one that points to the loop device.

Answer (score 12):

No. You must either reference the whole file, or you must copy the part of the file you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

It could be possible (to create a normal symlink pointing to a part of a file) on a filesystem which implements [the "file as directory" idea](http://kerneltrap.org/node/8250), which appeared--besides other authors--in [the plans for reiserfs](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.reiserfs.general/14227), but the reiserfs's implementation [wasn't liked](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/reiser4.html) for the problems the implementation caused.